# Columns in crystal report type boolean C #

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am doing reports with Crystal reports but I would like you to support me with the realization in this format (image)
[image]

I stuck in this step.
I already have the part where I create an xml and I call this in my cyrstal. The data of my query shows me in this format

```
IDINFORM |  NAME      |  DESCRIPTION      |   TIPO

 1       SERVICIO 1    SERVICIO NUMERO 1    PCHP
 1       SERVICIO 2    SERVICIO NUMERO 2    CONTRATACIÓN
```

Comment: Can you show us how would you like to show your data in report? This picture you provided is not very similar to your sample data.

Comment: Yes, if you note the type field can be PCHP or hiring, if the value is equal to the column of the report a check is displayed, but show without a check